# Module-level py.test fixtures that don't run on every submodule

Tags: python, pytest

Say I have a directory structure like this

```
$ tree
.
├── A
│   ├── __init__.py
│   ├── conftest.py
│   ├── test_set_1.py
│   └── test_set_2.py
├── B
│   ├── __init__.py
│   ├── conftest.py
│   ├── test_set_1.py
│   └── test_set_2.py
├── C
│   ├── __init__.py
│   ├── conftest.py
│   ├── test_set_1.py
│   └── test_set_2.py
├── conftest.py
├── pytest.ini
```

I want to define a `pytest` fixture that I can specify to run once for a particular top-level module (`A`, `B`, or `C`), but not once for every submodule (`test_set_1.py`, `test_set_2.py`, etc.)

How can I do this? Can I inject these dependencies inside the `__init__.py` files somehow?

Answer (score 0):

After a few hours I figured out a working answer: the `scope="session"` argument for a fixture applies to all submodules. So if `A/conftest.py` has a session-level fixture in it, it's only run once for all the tests in that submodule, but not run for tests in other submodules.